# how to prevent tox from deleting installed packages?

Tags: python, tox

I'm running tests with tox on Windows for a package that depends on numpy and scipy.

Since pip doesn't know how to install binaries, I installed the binaries of numpy and scipy manually. During a test run tox uninstalled numpy and scipy, and of course breaks right away because the dependencies are not found.

This happened on python 2.5 with old versions of numpy and scipy (for testing backwards compatibility).

My tox version (in python 2.6 which I use to run tox) is tox-1.4.2
The pip version in my 2.5 environment is pip-1.2.1.

This didn't happen when I set up my tox testing around 2 years ago.

Question: Is there a way to prevent tox from uninstalling numpy and scipy?

Extra question: Is there an alternative to tox/pip that works better on Windows and knows how to install binaries?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the virtualenv environment gets recreated (tox does not uninstall packages).

Tox once had support for easy_install - and that should re-appear, see https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/tox/issue/76/support-using-easy_install-especially-on

What you could try to do meanwhile is to install numpy/scipy on the base python environment and then use the `sitepackages=True` option, see http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#confval-sitepackages=True|False

Comment: Being able to use easy_install would help, but sitepackages=True doesn't really help since I'm testing compatibility with different versions of numpy, scipy and pandas, not just the ones I have in my base pythons.